# How can I increase the exploration in the Proximal Policy Optimation algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proximal-policy-optimization, exploration-exploitation-tradeoff

How can I increase the exploration in the Proximal Policy Optimation reinforcement learning algorithm? Is there a variable assigned for this purpose? I'm using the stable-baseline implementation: https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html